# get product id in woocommerce_before_calculate_totals filter

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to get product id of product of which add to cart button is clicked so that i can change the price of that product in the cart. The global product object is not working and is showing NULL. At present i have hard-coded product id ie $target_product_id = 48,  Here's my code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals',array($this,'add_custom_price' )); 

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

            $tac_dd_discounted_price = 10; 

            $target_product_id = 48;

            foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
                if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
                    $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
                }

            }

            /*global $woocommerce; 
            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(48);*/

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If set, `$_REQUEST['add-to-cart']` should give you the ID of the product that was just added to the cart.

Comment: i am getting product id on product page with $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] but when i do add to cart on shop page i get NULL

Comment: If you are adding to cart on the shop page then you are using AJAX.

Comment: yes, right, on shop page the add to car button is using ajax :)